# Click-through pseudoelement

Tags: html, css

Do somebody know how to make my `::after` click-through to be able to use the input under?

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}
form label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
form label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  top: -6px;
  left: -4px;
  z-index: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  max-width: 300px;
}
form input {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 22px 20px 26px 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
 <form action="">
  <label for="">
  </label>
  <input type="text">
 </form>
```

Comment: Control it how?

Comment: use normally. to be able to write text into the input

Comment: Do you mean to focus on the `input`?

Comment: yes, it's not able now, because the input is covered by the pseudoelement

Answer (score 1):

You can use `label` attribute to focus your `input` element. Make sure you remove the `pointer-events: none;` property. Else it will prevent the default `label` behavior.

```css
form {
  position: relative;
}
form label {
}
form label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid red;
  top: -6px;
  left: -4px;
  z-index: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
}
form input {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 22px 20px 26px 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="test">
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="test">
 </form>
```